# example for how to update a field in lucene.net index instead update all index

Tags: c#, api, indexing, lucene.net

I'm creating a search Engine by using Lucene.net in web Api , And I found a CRUD 
 code for update index like this

```
 private void CRUDIndex()
        {
            Video_List video = new Video_List();

            FSDirectory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(Path), new NativeFSLockFactory());
            bool isExist = IndexReader.IndexExists(directory);
            if (isExist)
            {
                if (IndexWriter.IsLocked(directory))
                {
                    IndexWriter.Unlock(directory);
                }
            }
            IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new PanGuAnalyzer(), !isExist, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
            while (bookQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                Document document = new Document();
                BookViewMode book = bookQueue.Dequeue();
                if (book.IT == IndexType.Insert)
                {
                    document.Add(new Field("id", book.ID.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
                    document.Add(new Field("title", book.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,
                                           Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
                    document.Add(new Field("content", book.Starring, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,
                                           Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
                    writer.AddDocument(document);
                }
                else if (book.IT == IndexType.Delete)
                {
                    writer.DeleteDocuments(new Term("id", book.ID.ToString()));
                }
                else if (book.IT == IndexType.Modify)
                {
                    writer.DeleteDocuments(new Term("id", book.ID.ToString()));
                    document.Add(new Field("id", book.ID.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
                    document.Add(new Field("title", book.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,
                                           Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
                    document.Add(new Field("content", book.Starring, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,
                                           Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
                    writer.AddDocument(document);
                }
            }
            writer.Dispose();
            directory.Dispose();
        }
```

its like add a new index after delete old index, but I just want to update fields and add it in to old index, And I dont know how to return to api controller about update index , So is there anyone who can give me some tips for it or better that show me a demo .I ll appreciate for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't. However, there is a more convenient method, `UpdateDocument(Term, IEnumerable<IIndexableField>)`.

```
else if (book.IT == IndexType.Modify)
{
    document.Add(new Field("id", book.ID.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    document.Add(new Field("title", book.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,
                           Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
    document.Add(new Field("content", book.Starring, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,
                           Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
    writer.UpdateDocument(new Term("id", book.ID.ToString()), document);
}
```

An index is not meant to be a database, it is a location where you can add data to make it *very fast* to search.

To utilize the update functionality from WebApi, you could piggy-back off of your database update (update the field(s) in the DB, read the whole record from the DB, update the index). Or, if you don't need to perform searches in real-time you could update the index in a batch process at regular intervals.

If your data updates very fast and you want to do searches on the live data there are a couple of options:

1. Use the [Near Real-time Search functionality](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/06/lucenes-near-real-time-search-is-fast.html) that the IndexWriter provides in conjunction with updating the index in real-time.
2. If you are willing to take a performance hit, you could subclass `Directory` and read the data directly from your database. There are already a couple of implementations that others have done (which you could either use directly or reverse engineer) - [LuceneNetSqlDirectory](https://github.com/MahyTim/LuceneNetSqlDirectory) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LuceneNetSqlDirectory/)) and [AzureDirectory](https://azuredirectory.codeplex.com/) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Store.Azure/)). If you do it this way, you can just update your data in the data source the traditional way.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your detailed explanation,but there still some error for this part
    writer.UpdateDocument("id",document), and it report that can't convert from “Lucene.net.Documents.Document” to "string", and actually this is my thesis topic, So its like I just want to show everyone that how lucene.net works including update index , So my plan was only  update the index, and show the result as Json code by using controller, So could you show me an example that by using this update method ,how to create a POST to return the result of this method ?

Comment: /*And there s parts code before CRUDIndex method*/
    public void StartNewThread()
        {
            
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(newWaitCallback(QueueToIndex));
        }
        private void QueueToIndex(object para)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (bookQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    CRUDIndex();
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: /*And there s parts code before CRUDIndex method*/
    public void StartNewThread()
    {
            
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(newWaitCallback(QueueToIndex));
    }
    private void QueueToIndex(object para)
    {
    while (true)
    {
    if (bookQueue.Count > 0)
    {
    CRUDIndex();
    }
    else
    {
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
    }
    }